# Date counts per customer in R

Tags: r

For the data below,

```
custid <- c(1,1,1,2,2,5,6,8,8,8)

date <- c(20130401,  20130403,  20130504,   20130508,   20130511,   20130716,   
      20130719, 20130423,   20130729,   20130707) 

money <- c(1, 2, 45, 3.56, 32.39, 1, 2, 3.90, 4, 8.5)

file <- data.frame(custid, date, money)
```

How do I get this output? I getting the Trans_count values by counting the dates. Thanks.

```
custid  Trans_count
1       3
2       2
5       1
6       1
8       3
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try either

```
 aggregate(cbind(Trans_count=date)~custid, file, length)
```

Or

```
library(data.table)
setDT(file)[, list(Trans_count=.N), .(custid)]
```

Or

```
library(dplyr)
file %>% 
    group_by(custid) %>% 
    summarise(Trans_count=n())
```

Or if you need a vector output

```
table(file$custid)
```